# How to use SetTextColor of TextView in Xamarin Android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I've searched long time but I couldn't find the correct answer.

I have Resources/values/colors.xml
I added `<color name="colorBottomBar">#D0D0D0</color>`

I want to set that color to my textview programmatically.
I tried this.

```
txtBottomHome.SetTextColor(Resources.GetColor(Resource.Color.colorBottomBar));
```

But `Resources.GetColor` is deprecated.
Please help me.

Answer (score 1):

I am not familiar with Xamarin, but in standard Android, `Resources.getColor(int)` was deprecated in favor of `Resources.getColor(int, Theme)`. The backwards-compatible way to get a color, then, was `ContextCompat.getColor(Context, int)`. Perhaps there is an equivalent in Xamarin.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've tried ContextCompat.getColor(Contex, int) too. but it says "cannot convert from 'int' to 'Android.Content.Res.ClorStateList'".

Comment: textview.SetTextColor needs Android.Content.Res.ColorStateList as parameter. How can I get it from ContextCompat.getColor?

Comment: Use `ContextCompat.getColorStateList()` instead